# My login system is not working php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Over here is my HTML code and it always says that wrong username and password, although I take data from database, so signed up users' username and password. But still not working. And it should be obligatory done with cookies.

```
<div class="container" id="driver" style="margin-top: 10%;">
        <h2>Авторизация</h2>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p><?php if($check == false ){ echo "Wrong password or login!"; } ?></p>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user">Имя пользователя:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Ваше имя пользователя" name="name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pwd">Пароль:</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Ваш пароль" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="login" style="background-color: #e6c300;">Войти</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And over here is PHP login code

```
<?php
include 'config.php';   
 include 'navbar.php';

if(isset($_COOKIE["taxi"]))
{
 header("location:index.php");
}

        $check = true;

        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `driver` WHERE username='$name'");
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        $a = var_dump($user_data);
        echo $a;
            if($user_data['password'] == $password){
                setcookie('taxi', $name);
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            else{
                    $check = false;
                }
        }
```

?>

And there is my navbar for defining whether sign in and sign up or logout

```
 <?php
                  if (isset($_GET['SignOut'])) { 

                        if(isset($_COOKIE['taxi'])){ 
                            setcookie('taxi', '' , time() - 3600); 
                            unset($_COOKIE['taxi']); 
                        } 
                  } 

                        if(isset($_COOKIE['taxi'])) 
                        { 
                          echo '<a href="index.php?SignOut" name="SignOut" id="SignIn"><p style="color:white; margin-top:15px;">Log Out</p></a>' ; 
                        } 
                        else { 
                        echo 
                        '<li class="nav-links"><a href="signup.php" style="color: white;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color: white;"></span> Register</a></li>
                         <li class="nav-links"><a href="login.php" style="color: white;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" style="color: white;"></span> Login</a></li>'; 
                        }

                ?>
```

Comment: As a side note, never store plaintext passwords in your database, use `password_hash` and `password_verify` to store and compare passwords. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: You are also vurnable to mysql injection. I suggest using `PDO` over mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php . Using prepared statements

Comment: @Joas don't u know how to fix my problem?

Comment: Try `var_dump($user_data)` to see if the data fetched from the database is correct. You might need to select the first index in the array that is returned by `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: how was the insert done? the post lacks detail and what the values are for everything.

Comment: @Joas it is dumping, I have checked it by echo, I'm beginner, please help me

Comment: Can you please include the dump in the question?

Comment: @Joas I've added

Comment: @Joas MySQLi also supports prepared statements

Comment: `<a href="index.php?SignOut" name="SignOut"` < href's do not bear the name attribute.

Comment: I meant include the output of the `var_dump` statement. You can leave out the password. On a side note, no need to echo the `var_dump` It already does the echo'ing for you.

Comment: @Joas array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "alon" ["username"]=> string(4) "alon" }

Comment: Things seem to be correct. One of the few things I can think of is `$password` not being set correctly, try `var_dump`'ing that.

Answer (score -1):

Check the result of `var_dump($user_data);` and be sure whether `$user_data['password']` has a value.

Or simply you can skip all those complex things and change the sql command to

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `driver` WHERE username='$name' AND password='$password'");'
```

and then check `mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1`. By that you can be sure that the entered username password are correct (as checked by the sql command) and also there is a valid record for that username and password by checking

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1){
   // There is a user with valid credentials
   setcookie('taxi', $name);
   header("Location: index.php");
}else {
   $check = false;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I can not suggest using `$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `driver` WHERE username='$name' AND password='$password'");'` It has certain downsides when looking SQL injection. I think it is good practice to compare the password with PHP and not with SQL.

Comment: Yes of course. But for here i used it just to give the answer to the question without complicating it for the person again and again :). But i admire your comment and i also advice for everyone not to use the pure SQL.